# How to do Kubernetes API server load test?

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

I would like to test how burden on Kubernetes API server when I collect logs using fluentd. I want to know how to do the test.. How can I know how frequent API call, memory usages, cpu usage and so on.(Are there any factors that I measure for the burden on k8s?) Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy it?

Comment: Thanks @MikołajGłodziak kube version is 1.18.9 and I deploy EKS